# Use the phpspreadsheet to set different colors in a cell, it will get error style on android and Mac

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I use the follwing code to set different colors in a cell and export it

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$rich_text = new RichText();
$rich_text->createText("P\n");
$text_run = $rich_text->createTextRun("A\n");
$text_run->getFont()->setColor( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_GREEN ) );
$text_run = $rich_text->createTextRun("N\n");
$text_run->getFont()->setColor( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED ) );
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue($rich_text);
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

$obj_writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$obj_writer->save(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.xlsx');
```

But open the file in different systems, I get **different result**, for example:

In windows, it looks normal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ODZi.png)

In mobile(I just try open it in android), colored rich text is not displayed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3bX7.png)

In Mac, colored rich text has strikethrough:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mR1d.png)

so, is it because of format compatibility? Do I need to set up anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used two cells to show the contents of different colors.